# What things can I simulate with box2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I want to use libdx and box2d, what things I can simulate with box2d or libgdx and I need something that can be useful in everyday life, it can be on any platform thanks.

Comment: A question asking us to find a thesis topic for you is off topic here.

Comment: Your question is not about java, libgdx or box2d. You are trying to find a brilliant idea.

Comment: I'm asking what are the things that I can simulate with it, so it's about the purpose of libgdx and box2d

Comment: @StormAsdg try to edit your question to make it less broad

Comment: You can simulate everything in the realm of physics, that is why this question is downvoted. So everything from a block of concrete falling down and a bouncing ball to explosions and the spring mechanics of a monster truck.

Comment: It's actually two questions. What can you do with libgdx, and of that, what does box2D limit and add to that ability range. It's not actually subjective, there is no external source that's going to cover it, and it is possible to give a conceptual answer that satisfies the question, and it's generally helpful to new programmers to know the limitations and capabilities of a framework, or two.

Comment: Box2D = anything that can move, or interact with immovable objects, can benefit from Box2D, and be done with Box2D. Some people say not all types of animation (in 2D) can be achieved with Box2D. I'd dare say it's the other way around, that Box2D enables every type of 2D animation known, with ease far greater than key framing. This more true, the more complex the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the effect of gravity on objects having different shapes and mass. You could allow the user to place objects and make the user specify the shape, mass ans size. then the user can watch as gravity causes the shapes to move in interesting patterns.